# Gradient with respect to the parameters of a specific layer in Pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, gradient-descent, detach

I am building a model in pytorch with multiple networks. For example let's consider `netA` and `netB`. In the loss function I need to work with the composition `netA(netB)`. In different parts of the optimization I need to calculate the gradient of `loss_func(netA(netB))` with respect to only the parameters of `netA` and in another situation I need to calculate the gradients wrt the parameters of `netB`. How one should approach the problem?

My approach: In the case of calculating the gradient wrt the parameters of `netA` I use `loss_func(netA(netB.detach()))`.

If I write `loss_func(netA(netB).detach())` it seems that the both parameters of `netA` and `netB` are detached.

I tried to use `loss_func(netA.detach(netB))` in order to only detach the parameters of `netA` but it doesn't work. (I get the error that `netA` doesn't have attribute detach.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradients are properties of *tensors* not *networks*.
Therefore, you can only `.detach` a tensor.

You can have different optimizers for each network. This way you can compute gradients for all networks all the time, but only update weights (calling `step` of the relevant optimizer) for the relevant network.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is what I ended up doing, but it seems to be really inefficient. It doesn't seem to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: @user127776 I suppose you can discard the gradients of the first network when computing the gradients of the deeper one (using, e.g., `with torch.no_grad():`) but if you want the gradients of the first layer, then the chain rule quite dictates that you compute the gradients of the second as well.